# How do I generate a device token using a Kreait FCM kit with new google update?

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

**While Using Kreait FCM**

I am trying to create a small application in php for sending push notification to user browser. I am using Kreait FCM kit and facing issue in token generation. below code is generated using bard api. but it is not working for me.request to everyone please provide me solution.

```
require \__DIR_\_ . '/vendor/autoload.php';  
use Kreait\\Firebase\\Factory;  
// Create a Firebase factory 
$factory1 = (new Factory)-\>withServiceAccount('service-account-file.json');  
// Create a Firebase messaging client 
$messaging1 = $factory1-\>createMessaging();  
// Get the device token 
$deviceToken1 = $messaging1-\>getToken();  
// Print the device token echo $deviceToken1;
```

We want to generate device token for each browser.

Answer (score 1):

The Kreait library runs on the server, while FCM only generates device tokens on the client-side devices that actually can receive messages. This means that it's not possible to generate a token with the Kreait library.

To **send** a messages from the Kreait library through FCM, you will:

- either need to get the device token on the device as shown in the Firebase documentation for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#access_the_registration_token), and [web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token) clients, send that token to your server, and then [send a message to the device token](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/7.x/docs/cloud-messaging.rst#send-messages-to-specific-devices) though the Kreait library.
- or subscribe the client to a topic, and then [send a message to that topic](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/7.x/docs/cloud-messaging.rst#send-messages-to-topics) through the Kreait library.